# Ubuntu 11.04 Static IP doesn't take

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I'm trying to set a static IP address in Ubuntu 11.04.  I did a server install.  I edited my `/etc/network/interfaces` file to include:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.0.1
```

When I do a `/etc/init.d/networking restart` this appears to take.  After awhile though, that `10.0.0.100` will turn into something dished out by the DHCP server.

My problem appears to be similar to this: [Ubuntu intrepid - static IP networking keeps restarting with DHCP](https://superuser.com/questions/204907/ubuntu-intrepid-static-ip-networking-keeps-restarting-with-dhcp)

But I don't have Gnome installed.  Is there anything else that's running in the background that could be doing this?  And if so, how do I disable it?

Comment: Have you deactivated DHCP for you auto eth0 connection?

Comment: Do I do that somewhere else besides the `iface eth0 inet static` line above? `dhclient` doesn't appear to be running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove or comment out the "auto eth0" line... if you are defining it as static below that line then you don't need it 'auto' in the first place.

My guess is that it is a race condition where since static can be set right NOW that is the one that gets completed first.. DHCP takes a bit longer to establish since there is a bit of server communication and hand-shaking that needs to take place, and thus when that finally completes it overwrites your already-finished-setting static IP.

I have not tested this on my machine as everything is unplugged due to a storm in my area, but this is my best untested guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching through log files. To be more specific, I have noticed that /var/log/syslog logs every IP change.

Few possible greps

`grep -i eth0 /var/log/syslog`

`grep -i 10.0.0.100 /var/log/syslog`

To search every log
`grep -i eth0 /var/log/*`

Answer (score 1):

If NetworkManager is installed (`dpkg -l network-manager` should display an entry beginning with `ii`), it may interfere with `ifupdown` settings.

Try updating `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, enabling `ifupdown` plugin and disabling managing of interfaces specified in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Mine looks like this:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

There may be other plugins activated; you should then add them at end of `plugins` stanza, separating names with comma, and appending the `[ifupdown]` section to the end of the file.